# How to open the exported file in Crystal Report using Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2019

I have exported a document using Crystal Report and Visual Studio and it work well, my question is that is it possible to open the file exported directly after the exporting.

I mean , is there any way to access the file and open it in ( Chrome, Microsoft Edge) using a C# code to print it ?

[image]

```
        CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
        {
            crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
            crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
        }
        // Refresh the Report
        cryRpt.Refresh();

        // Set the ReportSource 
        crysview.ViewerCore.ReportSource = cryRpt;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Look at bottom of page 15 : http://ees2.geo.rpi.edu/gis/docs78/CRW_REF.pdf

Comment: Can you please send me a screenshot rather than a link ?